# How to let a li take a relative width to parent ul

Tags: html, css

I'm a rookie for html and css and I'm trying to present a horizontal scroll list of images in my blog. After a bit of internet search. I have created one as below screenshot showed.

[image]

It seems good, but the width and height of `li` is hard coded pixel size, it may not adopt with small size screen device like mobile phone.

My question is could I get a relative size like below code in CSS style? I want to set `li.width == ul.width * 0.2` and `li.height == li.width * 1.5`. In iOS dev, we call it relative constraints, but I'm not sure what it should be called in Web dev. Sorry if my expression is not accurate.

BTW, there is a small black dot on the upper left corner of each li, how could I remove it?

```css
ul.movie-fans-images {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.movie-fans-images li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 542px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
}

.image1, .image2, .image3, .image4, .image5, .image6 {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623700802990-64369e024f41?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyOTI5MTU5NQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.movie-fans-images li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /*  relative*/
  width: ul.movie-fans-images.width * 0.20； 
  height: self.width * 1.5;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<ul class="movie-fans-images">
  <li class="image1"></li>
  <li class="image2"></li>
  <li class="image3"></li>
  <li class="image4"></li>
  <li class="image5"></li>
  <li class="image6"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To remove the dot: `ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS you have access to a few [relative units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units) which you can use to achieve what you want. In this case, you are setting your `ul` to `width: 100%;`, meaning 100% of its parent container. Therefore, you could simply set the width of each `li` to `width: 20%;`, which would mean 20% of the parent `ul` and also 20% of the `ul`'s parent container (whichever that may be).

```
ul.movie-fans-images li {
  width: 20%;
}
```

Another option would be to use viewport widths, a CSS unit which corresponds to 1% of the current device's browser width. Hence, 100vw is the same as 100% of the browser's width. With this, you could set the `ul` to always use the full available width of the user's device, and each `li`'s width to always be 20% of the device's width. This would in turn translate to what you want; each `li` to be 20% the width of the `ul`.

```
ul.movie-fans-images {
  width: 100vw;
}

ul.movie-fans-images li {
  width: 20vw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just try them both, percentage approach seems not work as I can't give a height to li, it is like url needs height from li, and li needs height of ul to make a relative height. But the 2nd approach is worked, I set ul width to `width: 56vw;` and li width and height to `width: 14vw; height: 30.352vw;`, here I manually calculate the height by times my image ratio to the width. And that link is helpful, I have save it.